# AngularJs error when usin track by $index with filter in a ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs

I'm having trouble when using a filter on a `ng-repeat` list and `track by $index`. I have a list of hotels and need to filter it by the city name.

The filter is working fine, this isn't the problem. The problem is the rendered list AFTER the filter. There is 2 situations at the moment:

- 1: If not using `track by` or using `track by item.id` there is no error at the beggining, but if I select an option I'll get the error: `[ngRepeat:dupes]`, which can be solved by using `track by $index`.
- 2: If using `track by $index` there is no errors, no matter what option I select. BUT, the list doesn't update properly. When I select one city the list will show the amount of results, but not the correct results. For example, if there is a total of 12 hotels and after the select there is only 4 results. The list will have 4 results, but it's not updating the results, it only reduce the list to 4 results but keeps the same order.

See this plunkr for example: https://plnkr.co/edit/J1QQCM?p=preview

If you filter by 'New York', the list will have only 4 results, but doesn't reorder the list to show the results from the city 'New York'. And this only happens when using `track by $index`.

This is the html I'm using:

```
<li ng-repeat="item in vm.mainList | filter:{location:filterLocation} track by $index">...</li>
```

And the array is something very basic, like this:

```
{
    "id": 0,
    "title": "Hotel The Mirage (Hotel & Casino)",
    "location": "Las Vegas, USA"
},
{
    "id": 1,
    "title": "Wynn Las Vegas",
    "location": "Las Vegas, USA"
},[...]~
```

---

> Note: I know I could solve this by using `track by item.id`, but this is a simple example. On the actual list I have more nested array and eventually I'll end up with id repeting. So I need to be able to use `track by $index`.

Comment: your plunkr is working

Comment: @z.a. select the city New York. The list will have 4 results, but all from Las Vegas.

Comment: @z.a. I updated the plunkr to show the $Index with the title. You can se the amount of results reduces properly, but not the order.

Comment: I removed both `track by $index` and the plunkr works perfect for me, with no errors at all.

Comment: https://plnkr.co/edit/mw8tJ1c7rAA50kklsViD?p=preview

Comment: @AlexChance but like I said, there is other filters which gives me the ng-dupe error, so I need to use track by $index.

Comment: Is it not because you're using one-time binding?

Comment: But I'm not applyt to the list itself, only to the objects inside the repeat. Isn't it supposed to work?

Comment: It would helpful to see the example that is causing the ng-dupe error, because in the example you provided, that error does not exist.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not working because you're using the one-time binding syntax.

I've forked your plunkr and used the regular syntax and it works:  https://plnkr.co/edit/mLaiqsrk9uUqnaYe308F?p=preview

```
  <ul>
    <li ng-repeat="item in vm.mainList | filter:{location:filterLocation} track by $index">
        <h4>{{ item.title }} - {{$index}}</h4>
        <p>{{ item.location }}</p>
    </li>
  </ul>
```

Comment: It actually worked. Itought the one bind would only affect it if using like this: `ng-repeat="item in ::vm.mainList`. Because then I'm only controlling the item inside the item and the filter is reordering the whole array. Do you know why?

Comment: @CelsomTrindade Sorry, I can't tell you enough about the internals to tell you why it works the way it does.  [This post](https://toddmotto.com/angular-one-time-binding-syntax/) suggests the issue might be that you are mixing a one-time binding on the individual properties with a regular one in the ng-repeat clause so you could try making them both one-time as well.

Comment: But then the whole array doesn't update. But ok, if it's a limitation we have, I'll deal with it. But thanks for the help!